# Javascript Regex to validate names

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have a requirement to handle no more than 2 consecutive leading characters in a name, in addition to:

non consecutive spaces, periods, spaces before or after a hyphen, and can't contain 3 consecutive digits.

Here's what I have so far, most requirements are cover, not eligantly I know, other than the 3 consecutive leading letters[a-z]:

```
/^((?!.*  )(?!.* - )(?!.*"")(?!.*\.\.)([a-z-+()"" \.\u0080-\uFFFF])\w{0,2})+$/i
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I detect and reject 3 leading consecutive characters?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a single "super-regex" when you can define individual requirements.

- No consecutive spaces: `/  /` (two spaces)
- No consecutive periods: `/\.\./`
- No space before or after a hyphen: `/ -|- /`
- No three consecutive digits: `/\d{3}/`

Check each of these individually. And here's the best part: you can tell the user *exactly* what is wrong with their desired name. That will save them a LOT of frustration!

Comment: Great answer, adding the check for two consecutive leading characters  would complete it..